# EF Core Could not load assembly ''. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project ''

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget

Исходные данные :
Visual Studio 2017
ASP.Net MVC Core 2.0
.NET Core 2.0

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

В консоль диспетчера пакетов ввожу команду `Add-Migration InitialCreate` и получаю следующее:

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Could not load assembly ''. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project ''.
```

Не помогло:

```
Update-Database -StartUpProjectName ProjectName
```

```
Enable-Migrations -StartUpProjectName ProjectName
```

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Project ProjectName
```

и другие советы по удалению, восстановлению, добавлению тех или иных файлов.

Прошу помощи, неделю не могу победить данную проблему, может кто пересекался с подобным случаем.

Answer (score 3):

У меня была та же проблема в солюшине с двумя проектами когда я случайно создал миграцию не в том проекте что надо. После удаления миграции с ненужного проекта все попытки создать миграцию в нужном проекте приводили к идентичной ошибке.

Эти действия мне помогли:

```
add-migration "[Migration Name]" -Project [Your Project Name]

update-database -Project [Your Project Name]
```

Чтоб не парится и каждый раз не писать имя проекта для миграций проще изменить проект по умолчанию как на скрине:

[image: Консоль менеджера пакетов Visual Studio]

Answer (score 0):

Самый популярный [ответ в англоязычной версии сайта stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678724/add-migration-causing-a-could-not-load-assembly-error), выбрать правильный проект в консоли, как показано в посте выше,

> This is embarrassing, but maybe this will help out a googler in the
> future. At the top of the "Package Manager Console" my default project
> was set to the wrong project. Changing that to my models project fixed
> it.

[image]
также необходимо проверить запускаемый проект в обозревателе решений Visual Studio [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)